# Asp.net Webapi Check originator's domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a webapi and I'm currently performing basic authentication, but I also want to check that the api is being called from an specific domain, how can I check if the call to the api was made from an specific domain?

I'm testing it with another C# application with an HttpClient, the request is being made successfully but no Origin header is set.

This is the call:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://xxxxxxx.apphb.com/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
        Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
            string.Format("{0}:{1}", "username", "password"))));

var obj = new { Name = "Test", ManageInternal = true, Signers = "test1,test2,test3" };

var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/document/postdocument", obj).Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at getting the IP address of the client, you can do  it like so:

```
if (request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_HttpContext"))
{
        var httpContext = (HttpContextBase)request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"];
        ipAddress = httpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;
}
else if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name))
{
        RemoteEndpointMessageProperty prop;
        prop = (RemoteEndpointMessageProperty)
                        request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name];
        ipAddress = prop.Address;
}
```

But IP address can be spoofed.

Comment: I mean something like HttpRequest.UrlReferrer in webapi

Answer (score 0):

Browsers enforce same origin policy on JavaScript. CORS is one way to workaround and with CORS, there is the Origin header involved. The client code you have is in C#, which means it runs in a server. There is no same origin policy or CORS for non-JavaScript clients. So, why do you need the origin header? BTW, any one can send the Origin header with whatever value they want.

Comment: Well, I just have a requirement in my API to check where it was called, it's there any other way to check this? I don't mind about CORS, I just need the domain where it was called